# How to fix font in Jmeter 5.1.1, Have fixed properties file

Tags: jmeter

Am new to Jmeter5.1.1. I see that GUI looks terrible upon download. Changed properties file but no luck. 
[This is how bad it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaY7r.png)
Any help is appreciated.
Below are my property file settings:

````
jsyntaxtextarea.wrapstyleword=true
jsyntaxtextarea.linewrap=true
#jsyntaxtextarea.codefolding=true
# Set 0 to disable undo feature in JSyntaxTextArea
#jsyntaxtextarea.maxundos=50
# Change the font on the (JSyntax) Text Areas. (Useful for HiDPI screens)
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=Hack
jsyntaxtextarea.font.size=11```
````

Answer (score 0):

Don’t touch properties.

Use last minor jdk 8 and use Darcula Laf which is the defailt.

Start jmeter using bin/jmeter.sh or bin/jmeter.bat

Answer (score 0):

User.properties changed helped for me however It did not quite help scaling the textbox size on the right side of the window.

Here are my user.properities changes.

```
jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=1.0
jmeter.toolbar.icons.size=48x48
jmeter.tree.icons.size=48x48
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=Hack
```

HTH